# If $f_j\to f$ in $L^1(\Bbb R^n)$ then $Tf_j\to Tf$ in $L^{1,\infty}(\Bbb R^n)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let's define $A:=\{f\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)\cap L^2(\Bbb R^n)\;:\;f\;\mbox{has compact support}\}$. So $A$ is dense in $L^1(\Bbb R^n)$.

Given then $f\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$; by density there exists $\{f_j\}_j\subset A$ such that $f_j$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$.

Let now $T$ be a linear operator of the strong type $(2,2)$ (i.e. if $h\in L^2$ then $Tf\in L^2$ too and $||Th||_2\le C||h||_2$), such that if $h\in A$ then $Th\in L^{1,\infty}(\Bbb R^n)$ and $||Th||_{1,\infty}\le C||h||_1$.

Moreover $T$ has an off-diagonal kernel $K(x,y)$, i.e. $K\in L_{\mbox{loc}}^2(\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\setminus\{\mbox{diagonal}\})$ such that for every $f\in L^2(\Bbb R^n)$ with compact support we have
$Tf(x)=\int_{\Bbb R^n}K(x,y)f(y)\,dy$ when $x\notin\operatorname{supp}(f)$.

Here $L^{p,\infty}(\Bbb R^n)$ denotes the weak $L^p$ space and $||\cdot||_{p,\infty}$ is its quasinorm; we know that $(L^{1,\infty}(\Bbb R^n),||\cdot||_{p,\infty})$ is complete.

Now, I suspect that $\{Tf_j\}_j$ converges in $L^{1,\infty}(\Bbb R^n)$ to $Tf$, but I do not see why this is true exactly. Could anybody help?

Comment: how do you define $Tf$ when $f\in L^1 \setminus A$? Note that since $f_j \to f$ you know $f_j$ is Cauchy, and by your norm bound so is $Tf_j$ in $L^{1,\infty}$.